# C# UWP Carousel selection change

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, carousel

I have a Carousel View that works really well.

```
<my:Carousel x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="Carousel" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ces}}" Margin="21,730,33,37" ItemMargin="20" ItemDepth="200" ItemRotationX="0" ItemRotationY="0" ItemRotationZ="0" InvertPositive="False" PointerPressed="Carousel_PointerPressed" SelectionChanged="Carousel_SelectionChanged" ManipulationStarted="Carousel_ManipulationStarted" >
    <my:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Bilder">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Width="250" Height="170" Source="{Binding Bild}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </my:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
 </my:Carousel>
```

I want to remove the border if the selection changed of a item (see picture below). How can I manage this? I know there is something with a Storyboard, but i dont know how to use it.

Please help me.
[image]

**EDIT**

If i try it with sample pictures which i created self with paint, is there no border. But as you can see the shoes does not have any border (See Pic 1 and 4). So why he add this border? Anyone know this issue?

Comment: Is this UWP Toolkit's Carousel control? It does not seem to have a border by default.

Comment: Yeah it is this UWP Toolkit's Control... I have a complete Transparent Page. I had the same issue with a Gridview, there i used a Storyboard. But i dont know how to manipulate the storyboard from a carousel.

Comment: There's a proposal to create an official UWP CarouselView [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/771).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Images are to large you Need to resize it to 250/170 and the broder will be gone.